# Eliminar ceros de triángulo generado en C

Tags: array, c

Quiero escribir un programa en C que muestre el siguiente patrón para input = 27.

```
0   2   3   9   10   20  21
1   4   8   11  19   22
5   7   12  18  23
6   13  17  24
14  16  25
15  26
27
```

Tengo el siguiente código

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
 int main() {
    int input = 27;
    int current = 0;
    int row, col;
    
    int pattern[7][7] = {0}; // Suponiendo que el patrón no exceda 7x7
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                pattern[j][i - j] = current++;
            }
        } else {
            for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
                pattern[j][i - j] = current++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
            if (pattern[row][col] <= input) {
                printf("%d\t", pattern[row][col]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

El error que sucede es que en lugar de imprimir un triángulo está imprime un rectángulo y está "rellenando" la otra mitad del triángulo con ceros.

```
0    2   3   9   10  20  21
1    4   8   11  19  22  0
5    7   12  18  23  0   0
6    13  17  24  0   0   0
14   16  25  0   0   0   0
15   26  0   0   0   0   0
27   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

¿Como hago para quitarlos y que me quede solo el triángulo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo necesitas colocar un `if` para cuando sea cero no imprima, exeptuando cuando el cero está en la posición `0,0`

Algo así:

```
for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
        if (pattern[row][col] <= input) { // <-- esto es necesario?
            if( (row==0 && col==0) || pattern[row][col]!=0){
                printf("%d\t", pattern[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Otra forma es disminuir el número de columnas en cada fila (en el 2do for)

```
for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < 7-row; col++) {  //disminuimos las columnas
       if (pattern[row][col] <= input) { // <-- esto es necesario?
           printf("%d\t", pattern[row][col]);
       }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```